# Uploads to launchpad.net not visible after dput

Tags: apt, ppa, launchpad, dput

I am trying to upload my backport of a package to my new repository on launchpad.net

`dput -u ppa:user/repository *.changes` completed successfully, but there are no changes on the PPA page.

`apt-add-repository` also fails with 'repository not signed'. Probably I've missed something while creating it

Comment: Did you receive any email?

Comment: No, I don't see any emails

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/592425/124466

Comment: and https://askubuntu.com/a/1463049/124466

Comment: There is some progress, but upload doesn't work:

```
Checking signature on .changes
gpg: /home/ubuntu/src/boost-backport/deb_save/boost1.83_1.83.0-1ubuntu1~jammy1_amd64.changes: error 58: gpgme_op_verify
gpgme_op_verify: GPGME: No data
```

Comment: Did you create an openpgp key and register it with launchpad? https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/ImportingYourPGPKey

Comment: Yes, I registered my pgp key and signed code of conduct

Comment: Oh it was my mistake, I tried to upload the binary '.changes' file. Now the source packet is in

Comment: Please write your own answer below so that it helps future users. You can also add a link to your PPA to increase its visibility :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to [Archisman Panigrahi](https://askubuntu.com/users/124466/archisman-panigrahi), the question is resolved:

1. [Create](https://launchpad.net/+help-registry/openpgp-keys.html)and [register](https://launchpad.net/+help-registry/import-pgp-key.html) your PGP key
2. Sign the code of conduct (click a link on your launchpad page)
3. Now upload the **source** .changes and wait

P.S. If someone needs a fresh (1.83) C++ boost for Ubuntu 22.04, you can take it here:

```
apt-add-repository ppa:maxim-razin/boost
```